# PHP Class Using Same Name as Trait Function

Tags: php, traits

I have the following code as a sample.

```
trait sampletrait{
   function hello(){
      echo "hello from trait";
   }
}

class client{
   use sampletrait;

   function hello(){
      echo "hello from class";
      //From within here, how do I call traits hello() function also?
   }
}
```

I could put all the details as to why this is necessary but I want to keep this question simple.  Extending from the class client is not the answer here due to my particular situation.

Is it possible to have a trait have the same function name as the class using it, but call the traits function in addition to the classes function?

Currently it will only use the classes function (as it seems to override the traits)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
class client{
   use sampletrait {
       hello as protected sampletrait_hello;
   }

   function hello(){
      $this->sampletrait_hello();
      echo "hello from class";
   }
}
```

Edit :
Whops, forgot $this-> (thanks JasonBoss)

Edit 2 :
Just did some research on "renaming" trait functions.

If you are renaming a function but not overwriting another one (see the example), both functions will exist (php 7.1.4) :

```
trait T{
    public function f(){
        echo "T";
    }
}

class C{
    use T {
        f as public f2;
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->f();
$c->f2();
```

You can only change the visibility :

```
trait T{
    public function f(){
        echo "T";
    }
}

class C{
    use T {
        f as protected;
    }
}

$c->f();// Won't work
```

Comment: Oooooooh. You can do this?!

Comment: Yes, you can even keep it public if you want to be able to call the method from an outer scope and therefore keep both methods

Comment: Wow, amazing :), trying this now

Comment: @AlexvanVliet Thanks for teaching me something new and useful today.

Comment: Is it possible to use the trait function hello() by default still if the class does not have the function hello to begin with?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan Look at my second edit, but you have to replace the protected with public

Comment: @ceeyajoz anytime !

Comment: I tried doing this but when the function was called nothing happened or printed, it was very strange, any ideas?

Comment: Which php version are you using ?

Comment: I made another question ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702562/use-trait-function-with-same-name-but-optionally

Comment: php 7 newest version FYI though so you know

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** You can do it this way also, you can use multiple function of a `trait` like this.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784738)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

trait sampletrait
{
    function hello()
    {
        echo "hello from trait";
    }
}

class client
{    
    use sampletrait
    {
        sampletrait::hello as trait_hello;//alias method
    }

    function hello()
    {
        $this->trait_hello();
        echo "hello from class";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example as well!